# the browser is outputing along with the array of objects printing. Please help me get rid off these

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
<div>
  <ul> 
     <% if @subjects.present? %> 
        <%= @subjects.each do |subject| %>
           <li>
              <%= subject.name %>
           </li>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[This is the screenshot of the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzSmY.png)

Comment: When asking for help debugging code, it's really important to provide all the information necessary IN the question, not as a link. Ancillary information can be linked, but the essential information, such as what you show in the screenshot, should be directly displayed. I'd recommend copying and pasting what the screen shows, and embed that in your question, formatted appropriately. See "[ask]" for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<%= @subjects.each do |subject| %>
```

to this:

```
<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
# ^-- look here
```

`<%=` evaluates ruby code and prints returned value, when `<%` only evaluates it.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line

```
<%= @subjects.each do |subject| %>
```

remove `=` from `<%=`.

Because, = prints out the object.